# Delete XML Nodes from StringBuilder in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, stringbuilder

I have structure nodes in `StringBuilder` [xml](http://pastie.org/pastes/9085129/text?key=qhhcpsxajsye4wqwyfjzug), now I want to delete some nodes that contain some year, for example I want to delete all nodes with this structure:

`<dropDownValue caption='2013' key='2013'>`     and all nodes inside it

The code from my xml:

```
<dropDownValue caption='2013' key='2013'>
    <dropDown default='sdrive23i.aspx#ulTopMenu'>
        <description caption='Модификация'>
        <modifyResource placeholder='modification'/>
        </description>
        <dropDownValue caption='sDrive23i' key='sdrive23i.aspx#ulTopMenu'/>
        <dropDownValue caption='sDrive30i' key='sdrive30i.aspx#ulTopMenu'/>
        <dropDownValue caption='sDrive35i' key='sdrive35i.aspx#ulTopMenu'/>
    </dropDown>
</dropDownValue>


<dropDownValue caption='2013' key='2013'>
    <dropDown default='30d.aspx#ulTopMenu'>
        <description caption='Модификация'>
            <modifyResource placeholder='modification'/>
        </description>
        <dropDownValue caption='3.0D' key='30d.aspx#ulTopMenu'/>
        <dropDownValue caption='3.6' key='36.aspx#ulTopMenu'/>
        <dropDownValue caption='4.8GTS' key='48gts.aspx#ulTopMenu'/>
        <dropDownValue caption='4.8S' key='48s.aspx#ulTopMenu'/>
        <dropDownValue caption='4.8Turbo S' key='48turbos.aspx#ulTopMenu'/>
    </dropDown>
</dropDownValue>


<dropDownValue caption='2013' key='2013'>
    <dropDown default='27.aspx#ulTopMenu'>
        <description caption='Модификация'>
            <modifyResource placeholder='modification'/>
        </description>
        <dropDownValue caption='2.7' key='27.aspx#ulTopMenu'/>
        <dropDownValue caption='S 3.4' key='s34.aspx#ulTopMenu'/>
    </dropDown>
</dropDownValue>

<dropDownValue caption='2013' key='2013'>
    <dropDown default='4s_4_8.aspx#ulTopMenu'>
        <description caption='Модификация'>
            <modifyResource placeholder='modification'/>
        </description>
        <dropDownValue caption='4S 4.8' key='4s_4_8.aspx#ulTopMenu'/>
        <dropDownValue caption='S 4.8' key='s_4_8.aspx#ulTopMenu'/>
        <dropDownValue caption='Turbo 4.8' key='turbo_4_8.aspx#ulTopMenu'/>
    </dropDown>
</dropDownValue>
```

Comment: Why are you using a StringBuilder at all? Just use an XML API...

Comment: @JonSkeet I insert my stringBuilder in xml document, how delete nodes inside XmlDocument?  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.LoadXml(strBuilder.ToString());

Comment: Well it's still not clear why you've got a StringBuilder. But I wouldn't use XmlDocument - I'd use LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this using XDocument:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load("yourfile.xml");

xml.Descendants("dropDownValue")
   .Where(e => e.Attribute("caption").Value == "2013" && e.Attribute("key").Value == "2013").Remove();

//your xml as a string again
var stringXml = xml.ToString();
```

Or this using XmlDocument:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("file.xml");

XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//dropDownValue[@caption='2013' and @key='2013']");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);

//your xml as a string again
var xmlDocString = xmlDoc.OuterXml;
```

Comment: Error 50'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Remove' 
and no extension method 'Remove' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Alright, I added a method if you want to use XmlDocument.